# Instanciated gameobject acts like it's a prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im working on modular space ships, customizable by the player. A ship has hardpoints, which hold modules, which in turn can hold more modules, etc. etc.

The code of a hardpoint at this moment looks very simple;

```
public class Hardpoint : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject holds; //this holds the prefab
    public ComponentObject.Type[] canHold;
    private GameObject heldInstance; //this holds an instance of the prefab

    public void SpawnComponent() {
        Clear();
        heldInstance = Instantiate(holds, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        heldInstance.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }

    public void RollThroughDecompression(CompressedComponent c) {
        heldInstance.GetComponent<ComponentObject>().Decompress(c);
    }

    public void Clear() {
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

however, it all acts like it's a prefab. because error messages i'm getting are:

`Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.
If you really want to remove an asset use DestroyImmediate (theObject, true);`

and

`Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption.`

I'm completely lost at this point. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why these errors keep popping up?

EDIT:
Some screenshots.

The expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

The actual result:

[image: Actual Result]

It all starts with the `EmptyHardpoint`. as you can see, it does spawn the cockpit, and sets the `EmptyHardpoint` as parent. But that's where the fun ends. further `Gameobjects` are handled as though they are prefabs.

Decompression code:

```
public void Decompress(CompressedComponent c) {
    componentType = (Type)Enum.Parse(typeof(Type), c.componentType);
    componentNumber = c.componentNumber;
    UpdateHardPoints();
    GameObject[] typeRepository = GetRepository(componentType);

    //update children 
    int point = 0;
    foreach (Transform child in typeRepository[componentNumber].transform)
    {
        Hardpoint hardpoint = child.GetComponent<Hardpoint>();
        if (hardpoint != null) {
            Debug.Log("Hardpoint found in " + child.transform.parent.name);
            if (c.hardpoints[point] != null) {
                //get the hardpoint's repository
                GameObject[] hardpointRepo = GetRepository((Type)Enum.Parse(typeof(Type), c.hardpoints[point].componentType));
                //set the hardpoint to hold this object
                hardpoint.holds = hardpointRepo[c.hardpoints[point].componentNumber];
                hardpoint.SpawnComponent();
                hardpoint.RollThroughDecompression(c.hardpoints[point]);
                point++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A `CompressedComponent` merely holds the type of the modular object. which get loaded from a repository in the scene (i know its messy, i'll work it out later.)

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the scene hierarchy for an example ship that leads to these errors? Are these errors thrown only when you call `Clear()`?

Comment: Did you `Instantiate` your `Hardpoint`?

Comment: @ Serlite `Clear()` only throws the first error message, i'm getting the second when setting the parent. @Cù Đức Hiếu I don't really know to be honest. i'm using networking and as player, i'm using a `hardpoint` with an additional script, to control the the movement.

Comment: Then I have a good reason to suspect your `Hardpoint` is `prefab`. Of course most actions on `GameObject` are disabled on `Prefab` by design. You can continue investigation to unveil my suspicion since it is very hard to debug further from my side with the information provided.

Comment: in the editor it does say (clone) so i do suspect it's instantiated. i'll add more code and screenshots to the question. Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Cù Đức Hiếu i figured out i was looking in the wrong area. during decompression i was looping through the actual prefab, instead of the transform. Fixed Code:

```
foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            Hardpoint hardpoint = child.GetComponent<Hardpoint>();
            if (hardpoint != null) {
                Debug.Log("Hardpoint found in " + child.transform.parent.name);
                if (c.hardpoints[point] != null) {
                    //get the hardpoint's repository
                    GameObject[] hardpointRepo = GetRepository((Type)Enum.Parse(typeof(Type), c.hardpoints[point].componentType));
                    //set the hardpoint to hold this object
                    hardpoint.holds = hardpointRepo[c.hardpoints[point].componentNumber];
                    hardpoint.SpawnComponent();
                    hardpoint.RollThroughDecompression(c.hardpoints[point]);
                    point++;
                }
            }
        }
```